# Apple Watchkit notifications

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have an iOS application where I incorporate rich notifications and add images and actions. Unfortunately these look great on the phone and very poor on the watch. I'm having a hard time finding out if I can customize the look of the watch kit notifications without actually providing functionality for a watch kit app.

I want to just customize the notification it receives from my iOS app. Can I do this? Is it just adding the watch target? If so will it show up on the watch face and if so what happens if i click it?

Comment: I think this link will help. https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/system-capabilities/notifications/

Comment: Thanks, I have read that before @Lumialxk but still not sold on if the extension can just be used to provide custom UI for notifications and not provide any functionality.